# Is there any convention to store methods not particularly related to any class? [java]

Tags: java, class, methods

I am currently learning Java and, while making a project, I created some methods that do not suit logically in any given class but are useful in the whole context of the project.

The best example I have is a method that splits camelCase worlds like this:

- splitCamelCase -> Split Camel Case.

I have thought about creating a new abstract class called Toolbox and storing those methods there, but I wonder if there is any convention or best practice regarding this topic.

Comment: why would  you use abstract class?

Comment: You can simply create a class Toolbox and store your methods as static methods

Comment: In my reasoning, that class is just for storing methods to use in other classes, not to create any new instance

Comment: No, abstact class - it's a bad idea because it says that it was created for extending, but it wasn't. So the good idea is to create a final utility class with many public static methods

Comment: @juanfran static methods are the one which you are looking for, as you can see with java.lang.Math class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not uncommon to have utility classes (commonly named `SomethingUtils`) when it just doesn't make sense to put a method in an existing class.

There's nothing inherently wrong with it, but if you find yourself having a lot of methods or utility classes, then your design might be a bit off and you're programming in a more procedural than object oriented way.

As mentioned in comments, you don't make it an abstract class. It's a class filled with static methods working entirely on the parameters passed to them.

Comment: In order to empasize its util character, you could make the class final and its constructor private. This "forces" any user of that class to only use the existing static methods. It is entirely optional to do so, of course.

Answer (score 1):

As kayaman sir  has said if you are having too many utility classes and method it means that you code is more procedural rather than object oriented.

Nut if you still want to have a class which is just used to provide some utility then you can have such a class in java , just put some static method in them.

One of the best example of such a class is java.lang.Math.

for example following code will work

```
class MyUtilityClass
{

private MyUtilityClass()
{
// no object creation will be allowed
}

// make as many static methods you want 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your ToolBox Class and then you declare it as a package. After that you can import your ToolBox at the beginning of classes you want to use the methods from that ToolBox.